# Binding failure prevents further validation on other fields in Playframework 2.2.1

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a form with multiple fields that I would like to validate when the user submits it.

The problem I have is that if one field doesn't bind due to, say, non-numeric characters in a field that should be bound to an int then the validate method in my POJO will not be called. This means that the user will only be shown the error for the field that should have been numeric, but will not show any errors for the other fields as the binding fails before the validate method is called.

I was wondering what is the best way round this? I want to be able to show to the user as many errors as possible, rather than having them fix one, submitting, and it failing again due to another field which didn't show as having an error previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, but if you look at Play's code you'll see that it's not possible.

[github.com/playframework - Form.bind(Map,String[])](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L305)

Play can only call `validate()` if it is able to instantiate your POJO. If the binding fails then there's no object to call validate on.

If you want all validation to happen at once then I think you have to either use all annotation-based validators (writing your own as necessary) or handle all of the validation yourself.